# How to get an error message with a unique constraint

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a form where a reference number gets added for a product. I've made this field unique because there will be no duplicate reference numbers.

<strike>The problem I'm having is when I add a reference number that is already attached to another product, I run into an exception `Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry for key 'reference'`. Instead I would like the form to display a message to the user to inform them that reference is already in use.</strike>

Edit: I have created a custom validator to check if the given reference already exists but I get the following error with this:

`Type error: Too few arguments to function Backend\Modules\Glasses\Domain\Glasses\Validator\Constraints\DuplicateReferenceValidator::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/ContainerConstraintValidatorFactory.php on line 52 and exactly 1 expected`

I can't seem to get my `GlassesRepository` in the `DuplicateReferenceValidator`

Data transfer object:

```
<?php

namespace Backend\Modules\Glasses\Domain\Glasses;

use Backend\Modules\Glasses\Domain\Brand\Brand;
use Backend\Modules\MediaLibrary\Domain\MediaGroup\MediaGroup;
use Common\Doctrine\Entity\Meta;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Backend\Modules\Glasses\Domain\Glasses\Validator\Constraints as CustomAssert;

class GlassesDataTransferObject
{

/*** Other fields ***/

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="err.FieldIsRequired")
     * @CustomAssert\DuplicateReference
     */
    public $reference;

/*** Other fields ***/
```

DuplicateReference.php

```
<?php


namespace Backend\Modules\Glasses\Domain\Glasses\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class DuplicateReference extends Constraint
{
    public $message = '"{{ reference }}" already exists.';
}
```

DuplicateReferenceValidator.php

```
<?php


namespace Backend\Modules\Glasses\Domain\Glasses\Validator\Constraints;

use Backend\Modules\Glasses\Domain\Glasses\GlassesRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;

class DuplicateReferenceValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private $repository;

    /**
     * DuplicateUserValidator constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(GlassesRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!$constraint instanceof DuplicateReference) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, DuplicateReference::class);
        }

        // custom constraints should ignore null and empty values to allow
        // other constraints (NotBlank, NotNull, etc.) take care of that
        if (null === $value || '' === $value) {
            return;
        }

        if (!is_string($value)) {
            // throw this exception if your validator cannot handle the passed type so that it can be marked as invalid
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($value, 'string');
        }

        $qb = $this->repository->createQueryBuilder('g');

        $qb->select('g.reference')
            ->where('g.reference = :reference')
            ->setParameter('reference', $value);

        $match = $qb->getQuery()->execute();

        if ($match) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->setParameter('{{ reference }}', $value)
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

I needed to add the entity manager to my `services.yml` file in order to be able to access it in the validator.

```
Backend\Modules\Glasses\Domain\Glasses\Validator\Constraints\DuplicateReferenceValidator:
        attributes:
            - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

Comment: [Autowiring](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/autowiring.html) could handle that.